# Bootstrap Glyphicon align with text box

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, webforms

[image]I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
         <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtAccountNumber" CssClass="control-label ">10 Digit Account Number</asp:Label>
     <asp:TextBox  onkeyup="isAccountValid();" CssClass="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Please enter your account number" runat="server" ID="txtAccountNumber" />
     <span id="isAccountValid" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" style="color: lightgreen;"></span>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
     <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtEmail" CssClass="control-label ">Email</asp:Label>
     <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Please enter your email" runat="server" ID="txtEmail" />
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I am having a hard time putting the glyphicon next to the text box. Any suggestions? I prefer pure CSS or Bootstrap classes...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adding `form-inline` to the row div would do the trick.

```
<div class="row form-inline">
```